# How to get touch id authentication information?

Tags: ios, ios8, passwords, biometrics, touch-id

Is there any way to get some kind of touch id authentication string? I want to use it as a password and associate it with a username.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't a way to do this. The LAContext class gives you several status (pass, fail, cancel, etc...) but you do not get any additional data. Here are the possible status values from the LAError.h file.

```
    /// Authentication was not successful, because user failed to provide valid credentials.
    LAErrorAuthenticationFailed = kLAErrorAuthenticationFailed,

    /// Authentication was canceled by user (e.g. tapped Cancel button).
    LAErrorUserCancel           = kLAErrorUserCancel,

    /// Authentication was canceled, because the user tapped the fallback button (Enter Password).
    LAErrorUserFallback         = kLAErrorUserFallback,

    /// Authentication was canceled by system (e.g. another application went to foreground).
    LAErrorSystemCancel         = kLAErrorSystemCancel,

    /// Authentication could not start, because passcode is not set on the device.
    LAErrorPasscodeNotSet       = kLAErrorPasscodeNotSet,

    /// Authentication could not start, because Touch ID is not available on the device.
    LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable  = kLAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable,

    /// Authentication could not start, because Touch ID has no enrolled fingers.
    LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled   = kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled,
```